# Windows symlinks

Tags: windows, powershell, symlink

I am trying to create a symbolic link between a "reports" folder sitting inside each users home directory to the "reports" folder in the master.

In short I am trying to convert the following in a language Windows will understand

```
for all users
   cd /path/to/firstname.lastname/reports
   ln -s ../masterUsername/reports
```

I tried

```
MKLINK /d /path/to/masterUsername/reports /path/to/firstname/lastname/reports
```

first user went fine but it complains that the link already exists for the second user.

I also tried

```
/j
```

I am not sure what exactly is the difference between Junction and Directory in this case.

Help please!!

Comment: You got the order of params wrong: MKLINK /d /path/to/firstname/lastname/reports /path/to/masterUsername/reports is the correct form. See @ansgar's response below for details.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux/Unix you use

```
ln -s target [linkname]
```

If `linkname` is omitted it defaults to the basename of `target`.

In Windows, however, the order of the arguments `linkname` and `target` is reversed and both of them are required:

```
mklink /d linkname target
```

Also, `mklink` is a `CMD` builtin, so it can't be used by itself in PowerShell. You need to use it like this:

```
cmd /c mklink /d linkname target
```

If (for instance) you want to create a symbolic link in all user profiles, something like this should do:

```
$target = 'C:\path\to\masterUsername\reports'

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users' | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  cmd /c mklink /d (Join-Path $_.FullName 'reports') $target
}
```

Note that you need admin privileges for using `mklink`.

**Edit:** For linking `reports` folders from each user directory to one central report directory you'd do something like this:

```
$userdir = 'C:\Users'
$hub     = 'C:\path\to\masterUsername\reports'

Get-ChildItem $userdir | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  $userReports = Join-Path $_.FullName 'Documents\reports'
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $userReports) {
    cmd /c mklink /d (Join-Path $hub $_.Name) $userReports
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create 1 link for multiple targets.. maybe I have not clarified that. I have a reports folder in each user's directory those need to be linked to a reports folder in a master user's directory

Comment: @user2247823 Sorry, that wasn't clear to me from your question, since the `ln` example you provided in your question won't do what you just described. See updated answer.